# Populate a two dimensional array with a single loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried below code to fill a two dimensional array in Excel VBA and I was able to get the desired results. I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this or if you foresee any technical issue once I have a significantly large size of data in real case situations. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated for improvement.

```
Sub test_selection()
' My below array is based on values contained within
' selected cells
' The purpose of using two dimensional array is to 
' keep values in one column of array 
' while retaining cell addresses in 2nd 
' dimension to print some info in relevant cells
' offset to the selected cells

Dim anArray() As String

firstRow = Selection.Range("A1").Row
LastRow = Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.Count).Row
colum = Selection.Columns.Column
arrSize = LastRow - firstRow

ReDim anArray(0 To arrSize, 1)
cnt = 0

For i = firstRow To LastRow
    anArray(cnt, 0) = CStr(Cells(i, colum).Value2)
    anArray(cnt, 1) = Cells(i, colum).Address
    cnt = cnt + 1
Next i

Call TestGetFileList(anArray)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a *significantly large size of data*, that loop through the worksheet is going to be slow. Probably better to grab all of the data at once and reprocess it in memory.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_selection()
' My below array is based on values contained within
' selected cells
' The purpose of using two dimensional array is to
' keep values in one column of array
' while retaining cell addresses in 2nd
' dimension to print some info in relevant cells
' offset to the selected cells

    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As String, anArray As Variant

    With Selection
        c = Split(.Cells(1).Address, "$")(1)
        r = Split(.Cells(1).Address, "$")(2) - 1
        anArray = .Columns(1).Cells.Resize(.Rows.Count, 2).Value2
    End With

    For i = LBound(anArray, 1) To UBound(anArray, 1)
        anArray(i, 1) = CStr(anArray(i, 1))
        anArray(i, 2) = "$" & c & "$" & i + r
    Next i

    TestGetFileList anArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi 4618, I would like to share with you overall scope of this sub procedure & others. The 'Selection' in my subroutine is normally a small range, say 10-20 rows containing order numbers but the designated invoices folder on hard drive might have several hundred invoices for each year. I think digging into folders and subfolders using FSO is slow and therefore should be improved. So let me know if you have a better FSO pattern which should target only those files contained within my array of Orders.